# Can PHP mysqli set timeout on connect attempt?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timeout

I've this line to connect to MySQL db and just wonder if there's a way to set a timeout for connect attempt?

```
$db = new mysqli($server, $usr, $passwd, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can specify a timeout explicitly for an attempt to connect from your php program to a MySQL database using mysqli.

It's a little hairy, though.  When you use `new mysqli()` you use a pool of reusable connections. If you want to set a timeout, or any other option, you need to use `real_connect` instead, like the following:

```
$timeout = 30;  /* thirty seconds for timeout */
$link = mysqli_init( );
$link->options( MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, $timeout ) ||
     die( 'mysqli_options croaked: ' . $link->error );
$link->real_connect($server,  $usr, $passwd, $dbname) ||
     die( 'mysqli_real_connect croaked: ' . $link->error );
```

There's a decent explanation here: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. I had no solution for database incidents in a web application. Now I can detect a timeout and toggle to the slave db. Cheers!

Comment: It didn't happen to work for me on a hostgator shared server; however, this is really good to know.